# Avoid Optional Words with Regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to realize a Regex for this:

```
Line 1: OPEN_SESSION (AAAA) xxxx.yyyy
Line 2: OPEN_SESSION zzzz
```

to get **xxxx.yyyy** and **zzzz** but i can't avoid that annoying parenthesis. I tried with:

```
OPEN_SESSION[\s](?:\(*AAAA*\))?([A-Za-z0-9-_.]{4,20})
```

but it didn't work. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expression is almost correct. The only reason it wouldn't work is that you forgot the optional space after (AAAA). Also, it should also discard the match until that point - i.e., the match (as it is in your solution) includes `OPEN_SESSION` (with space included). If you want that excluded:

PCRE version:

```
OPEN_SESSION[\s](?:\(*AAAA\)*[\s])?\K([[:alnum:]-_\.]{4,20})
```

`\K` discards everything until that point.

And the only other change I did (except for adding an extra [\s] before the \K), is that I used the character class [:alnum:] which is practically short for [A-Za-z0-9]. But this is a matter of personal preference - it doesn't change the final result.

Java version:

```
(?:OPEN_SESSION[\s][(]*[A]*[)]*[\s]?)([A-Za-z0-9_\-.]{4,20})
```

Comment: I tested it on https://regex101.com/ and it does match `xxxx.yyyy` and `zzzz`. What is the result that you seek?

Comment: I figured it out - \K doesn't work on regexr.com for some reason. But it would work in java. 
Here is a version that works in regexr: `(?:OPEN_SESSION[\s][(]*[A]*[)]*[\s]?)([A-Za-z0-9_\-.]{4,20})` It marks in blue the whole text (even the non-captured one), but if you rollover with the mouse, you can see that the 1st and only captured group is `xxxx.yyyy` or `zzzz`

Comment: It also take the AAAA

Comment: [regex101.jpg](http://i.imgur.com/Dt1Q3Bs.jpg) - here is how it works with the \K in regex101.com;
[regexr.jpg](http://i.imgur.com/7sVicSI.jpg) - here is on regexr.com - you can see that group 1 is `xxxx.yyyy`.
If you want to also capture `OPEN_SESSION`, here is another version: `(OPEN_SESSION[\s])(?:[(]*[A]*[)]*[\s]?)([A-Za-z0-9_\-.]{4,20})` - here group 1 is `OPEN_SESSION` and group 2 is `xxxx.yyyy`

Comment: regexr works with javascript flavour. If you need javascript regex, you might want to change the java tag into javascript. For java, my answer works - as you can see in regex101.com.

Comment: This regex won't work in Java because of `\K` - it works in PCRE and Boost only. regex101 does not support Java regex syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You might have forgotten the parenthesis at the end of your regex :

`OPEN_SESSION[\s](?:\(*AAAA*\))?([A-Za-z0-9-_.]{4,20})`

But that still doesn't work.

Try this one :

`OPEN_SESSION\s(?:\(AAAA\))?([\w \.]{4,20})`

If you need to accept space characters in the second part, just add a `\_` to the regex :

`OPEN_SESSION\s(?:\(AAAA\))?([\w \_ \.]{4,20})`

Comment: I forgot it. It's not that the problem

Comment: you mean in the second part (xxxx and zzzz) ?

Comment: Like Line 1: OPEN_SESSION (AAAA) xxxx.yyyy stuff

Comment: It don't have to take the space it have to stop after the xxxx.yyyy